# Cancel scrolling from event on Mobile IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, touch, dom-events

This construct lets users draw on a html5 canvas. On other browsers such as mobile Safari and Chrome, `.preventDefault()` and `.stopPropagation()` successfully cancel any scrolling while moving the finger over the canvas. However mobile IE still scrolls, making it impossible to draw.

Is there any way to cancel scrolling?

```
startDrawing: function(e) {
    var me = this;

    if (!me.isLocked) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        me.isDrawing = true;

        me.context.beginPath();
        me.context.moveTo(e.offsetX || e.layerX, e.offsetY || e.layerY);
    }
},

draw: function(e) {
    var me = this;

    if (me.isDrawing) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        me.context.lineTo(e.offsetX || e.layerX, e.offsetY || e.layerY);
        me.context.stroke();
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS does the trick for IE 11 (prefixed for IE 10)

```
touch-action: none
```

Touch events are pointer events in IE11 (prefixed for IE 10).